# Mysql EXTRACTVALUE function using in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a message xml like this

```
<message  id="31" type="chat" xml:lang="en"><body>sds</body></message>
```

i need a select query for satisfy which xml having id="31" attribute value
I just pass  id value to select query

```
select * from table where ExtractValue(xml,'/message[@id="31"]') = 31
```

But this query return "No rows found" result
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XPath `boolean` function to check for the presence of root level `<message>` tags whose id is 31:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ExtractValue(`xml`, 'boolean(/message[@id=31])')
```

**Update:**

If you want to delete records with ID of 31, then you can try:

```
DELETE
FROM table
WHERE ExtractValue(`xml`, 'boolean(/message[@id=31])')
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I have matching record in my DB, then what i get the result

Comment: i need to delete that row which satisfy id =31